# Iterating through an array of objects with nested array and objects to add my own object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of nested objects and arrays:

```
const myArr = [
  {
    workoutName: "workout1",
    exercises: [
      {
        exerciseName: "Bench Press",
        sets: [
          {
          // some props and vals
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        exerciseName: "Deadlift",
        sets: [
          {
          // some props and vals
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        exerciseName: "Squat",
        sets: [
          {
          // some props and vals
          },
        ]
      },
      // more exercises
    ]
  }
]

const compareVal = "Deadlift";
const mySetObj = {//some data}
```

I want to iterate through the exercises array of objects and compare the `exerciseName` value for each object with the `compareVal` for a match. If it does match, I want to be able to add `myObj` as a value to that object's `sets`array. Each of the `exerciseName` values are unique, so it would not be necessary to iterate through all of the exercises after finding a match.

Is there a way I can achieve this elegantly?

Comment: It looks like `myArr` is an array itself. Do you need to do this for each workout routine, or just for `myArr[0]`?

Comment: Just myArr[0], the array will not have more than one workout routine.

Comment: OK, I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like an array `find` method would be sufficient. Note that, in this solution, we use a `forEach` loop on the `myArr` array since it seems you might want to do this for each routine.

```js
myArr.forEach(routine => {
  const ex = routine.exercises.find(e => e.exerciseName === compareVal);
  ex.sets.push(mySetObj);
})
```

**Update:** Since you just need this for `myArr[0]`, this can be simplified as follows:

```js
const ex = myArr[0].exercises.find(e => e.exerciseName === compareVal);
ex.sets.push(mySetObj);
```

And here it is working:

```js
const myArr = [
  {
    workoutName: "workout1",
    exercises: [
      {
        exerciseName: "Bench Press",
        sets: [
          {
          // some props and vals
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        exerciseName: "Deadlift",
        sets: [
          {
          // some props and vals
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        exerciseName: "Squat",
        sets: [
          {
          // some props and vals
          },
        ]
      },
      // more exercises
    ]
  }
]

const compareVal = "Deadlift";
const mySetObj = { some: "data" };

const ex = myArr[0].exercises.find(e => e.exerciseName === compareVal);
ex.sets.push(mySetObj);

console.log(myArr);
```